# Does this if condition can be manipulated using song_genre value?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my code below...

```
$song_genre = $_GET['song_genre'];
if($song_genre=='bangla'||$song_genre=='hindi'||$song_genre=='english'){ 
    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `song_genre` = '$song_genre'";
    mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
}
```

Comment: Please post proper question.

Comment: yes it can. but please be specific what you want here

Comment: I would do, `if(in_array($song_genre, ['bangla','hindi','english'])){...}` but I'm lazy programmer...

Comment: Not only can it be manipulated, but I can manipulate your entire database with it through SQLInjection, I suggest you do some research on "Prepared statements"  And "SQL Injection Attacks"

Comment: I want to know how this if condition can be true if $_GET['song_genre'] is not equal to bangla or, hindi, or, english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how this if condition can be true if $_GET['song_genre'] is not equal to bangla or, hindi, or, english.

Since you are using [loose comparison (`==`) instead of strict comparison (`===`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp) the values will [type juggle](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php), so a 0 would be true:

```
var_dump(0 == "bangla"); // bool(true)
```

But since anything in `$_GET` will always be a string or an array, there should be no practical way to get the if clause to evaluate to true with anything but the three strings. Nevertheless, use strict comparison.

On a side note: [please use prepared statements to guard against sql injection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: Why zero is equal to any string value??

Comment: @Rangan because you are using loose comparison and the value will type juggle. Please follow the provided links in my answer to understand this concept if it's unclear to you.

Answer (score 0):

if the $_GET['song_genre'] becomes 0 (intvalue) this if statement will be broken .

```
$song_genre = 0 ; // will break the statement
```

better check for

```
if(!empty($song_genre)){
//your code
}
```